# Spring 2.3.4.RELEASE, Mybatis.Spring.boot 2.1.3 : Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am using idea to build artifact based on a Mybatis demo project.
It is really a simple demo containing:

main class:

```
@MapperScan(basePackages = "thusca.testMybatis.mapper")
@SpringBootApplication()
public class SampleMybatisApplication{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleMybatisApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

mapper:

```
@Mapper
public interface CityMapper {

    @Select("SELECT * FROM CITY WHERE state = #{state}")
    City findByState(@Param("state") String state);

}
```

model:

```
public class City implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String state;

    ...
}
```

service:

```
@Service
public class mysqlService{
    @Autowired
    CityMapper mapper;
}
```

It runs correctly when I run it using GUI mode. However if I build artifact and run it using command `java -jar xxx.jar`. It always fails and reports error `ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required`.

I googled it and tried all solutions but no one worked.

here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>testxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>testMybatis</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>testMybatis</name>
    <description>testxxx.testMybatis</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

and application.properties

```
server.port=8083

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=xxxxxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.max-idle=10
spring.datasource.max-wait=1000
spring.datasource.min-idle=5
spring.datasource.initial-size=5
server.session.timeout=10
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8
```

ps: for my project, only idea can be used to build artifact(jar), mvn command cannot be used.

Comment: 1 thing that is missing is the `spring-boot-maven-pugin` to build a proper spring boot jar.

Comment: @M.Deinum but it is necessary for me to use idea to build jar not mvn command

Comment: You need to use maven else you won't have a proper jar. So either run maven from within Intellij or use the commandline. Also why does it matter how you create the jar? You are using maven and that should be used to create the jar, else using maven adds not much.

Comment: d@M.Deinum my project depends a special jar file that will crash if I package the whole project using mvn

Comment: Then you cannot use Spring Boot as it requires a specially packaged jar. Why would it fail when packaging with mvn. Then you should fix that